# Solving given limit with other limits

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

Did this problem give enough information to evaluate the limit? I don't know how to approach this problem because they gave me the limits of 3 different functions and I can only plug one of them into the 4th limit and I'm still left with (x-c) in the denominator. Is there something I'm missing? Can I use the formal definition of a limit (delta-epsilon) to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} h(x)=-2 \\\lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{h(x)}{x-c}=\frac{-2}{c-c}\\\lim_{x\rightarrow c^{+}} \frac{h(x)}{x-c}=\frac{-2}{c^{+}-c}=-\infty\\and\\\lim_{x\rightarrow c^{-}} \frac{h(x)}{x-c}=\frac{-2}{c^{-}-c}=+\infty\\so\\the -limit-does-not-exist
$$